# WF DesignerView is null after GetService is invoked

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I am trying to start a new designer in my application but i get an error at :

```
     DesignerView designerView = wd.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
```

so the designerView will be null here. I dodn't know what i am missing.

This is the code from my LoadWorkflowFromFile(string fileName) method.

```
            workflowFilePathName = fileName;
            workflowDesignerPanel.Content = null;
            WorkflowPropertyPanel.Content = null;
            wd = new WorkflowDesigner();

            wd.Load(workflowFilePathName);
            DesignerView designerView = wd.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
            designerView.WorkflowShellBarItemVisibility =                              ShellBarItemVisibility.Arguments
                                                           | ShellBarItemVisibility.Imports
                                                          | ShellBarItemVisibility.MiniMap
                                                          | ShellBarItemVisibility.Variables
                                                          | ShellBarItemVisibility.Zoom;
            workflowDesignerPanel.Content = wd.View;
            WorkflowPropertyPanel.Content = wd.PropertyInspectorView;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I know that it may be a bit late to answer, but it'll probably help others in the future.*

About a week ago, I encountered the same problem. Turned out that I tried to get the DesignerView, while I was still in the initialization code of the UserControl that contained the rehosted WorkflowDesigner.

I still initialized the WorkflowDesigner there, but after moving the GetService call to the Loaded method, it actually returned the DesignerView:

```
public partial class MyDesignerControl : UserControl
{
    private WorkflowDesigner wd;
    private string workflowFilePathName;

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e) {
         base.OnInitialized();
         wd = new WorkflowDesigner();

         wd.Load(workflowFilePathName);
         workflowDesignerPanel.Content = wd.View;

         // this doesn't work here:
         // var designerView = wd.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
    }

    private void MyDesignerControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // here it works:
        var designerView = wd.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();

        // null check, just to make sure it doesn't explode
        if (designerView != null) {
            designerView.WorkflowShellBarItemVisibility =
                     // ShellBarItemVisibility.Imports | <-- Uncomment to show again
                        ShellBarItemVisibility.MiniMap |
                     // ShellBarItemVisibility.Variables | <-- Uncomment to show again
                     // ShellBarItemVisibility.Arguments | <-- Uncomment to show again
                        ShellBarItemVisibility.Zoom;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Once I had the DesignerView, the WorkflowShellBarItemVisibility part worked as expected.

(For the sake of completeness: don't forget to register the method to the corresponding event in XAML):

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Namespace.Here.MyDesignerControl"
             ...
             Loaded="MyDesignerControl_Loaded">
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting this!  I ended up with a slightly different way of getting to it that matched my code, but you steered me in the right direction! The trick was to cast the view to a FrameworkElement so you can hook the loaded event

```
_wf = new WorkflowDesigner();
((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)_wf.View).Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    var designerView = _wf.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
    if (designerView != null)
        designerView.WorkflowShellBarItemVisibility =
                    ShellBarItemVisibility.Variables |
                    //ShellBarItemVisibility.Arguments |  
                    //ShellBarItemVisibility.Imports |     
                    ShellBarItemVisibility.PanMode |
                    ShellBarItemVisibility.MiniMap |
                    ShellBarItemVisibility.Zoom;
};
```